# What workaround to pass an instance variable to the super constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Ok, so this is not allowed:

```
public class ServiceError extends RuntimeException {

    private final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    public ServiceError(...) {
        super("{" + uuid.toString() + "} " + ...); // error on reference to uuid
    }
```

But how can I do what I want? There is no `Exception.setMessage`, so I can't change the message after the super constructor has been completed, I need to pass the UUID in the constructor.

Comment: Overriding `getMessage()` is a very specific solution. Are there more general possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to override `getMessage()` in your class to return the message that makes sense for your exception class.

As an example, here is what [`ActivationException.getMessage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/rmi/activation/ActivationException.html#getMessage%28%29) looks like in my JDK:

```
public String getMessage() {
    if (detail == null) 
        return super.getMessage();
    else
        return super.getMessage() + 
            "; nested exception is: \n\t" +
            detail.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would do this:

```
public class ServiceError extends RuntimeException {

    private final UUID uuid;

    public ServiceError() {
        this(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    private ServiceError(UUID uuid) {
        super("{" + uuid.toString() + "} " + ...);
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

Basically this is just a matter of changing where the `UUID.randomUUID()` call is made, and using a constructor parameter both to construct the superconstructor argument and to save the value to the field afterwards.

Comment: I'm going with the other method because I actually have many constructors and don't want to do duplicate them all, but this is the more reusable one (in classes where overriding won't do the trick).

Comment: @Bart: You don't need to duplicate them all: you just make all the existing constructors call to a single one with all the possible parameters, including the UUID. Should be pretty straightforward. Personally I *far* prefer this approach to overriding - it's not like you're *really* trying to provide different logic.